# Installing phpdbg on the Mac

Tags: php, macos, phpdbg

I'd like to install phpdbg on my Mac but am falling at the first hurdle of the installation guide here:

```
http://phpdbg.com/docs/introduction
```

There is no `/usr/src/php-src/sapi` on my Mac and I can't find the `php-src` directory on my system.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your issue is you didn't install PHP on your machine. Did you? (No offense meant if you did, just the simplest solution is often the right one)
  That being said, it's easier to install via [brew](http://brew.sh/)

Run:
    `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` to install brew.

From there, type `brew install php56 --with-phpdbg`

Comment: phpdbg not found